# React style width based on length of props

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a react component:

```
const TeamRow = props => {
  const items = props.team.map((item, index) => {
    const con_width = 100 / props.team.length;
    const Style = {
      team_img: {
        width: "50px",
        height: "auto"
      },
      member_container: {
        float: "left",
        width: `{con_width}%`
      }
    };
    return (
      <div style={Style.member_container}>
        <img style={Style.team_img} src={logo} />
        <p>{item.name}</p>
        <p>{item.bio}</p>
      </div>
    );
  });
  return <div>{items}</div>;
};
```

The idea is to have a set of divs next to one another horizontally. The width of each div should equal 100% divided by the number of divs.
`{con_width}` is calculated correctly, but in the web inspector, there is no 'width' style at all. It just gets ignored by react. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to change  width: `{con_width}%` to  width: `${con_width}%`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
width: `{con_width}%`
```

To

```
width: `${con_width}%`
```

You need to use ${} in template literals to print the value